# Retrieving sql database records based on time continuously

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an online database CUSTOMERINFO with more than 100k details stored like following format `Cust Id, Customer name, Addr, Phone,.......,Call back time`

I want to retrieve data when call back time equals current time automatically.

I have designed front end with Java and currently 10 employees working with the database and now they are manually retrieving the data by ID,..

I know `select` command is very useful to retrieve but I want it to do automatically instead of calling each time manually.

---

Edited:

When the customer data is retrieved from table, either we will set `another call back time` or `no call back` and then pushed into table again.. In the next time if `no call back` is set in the place of call back time that row no need to be retrieved.

Comment: Automatically *when?*, *how often?*, *under what conditions?*, *triggered by what event?*, etc,

Comment: When 'call back time' equals to the 'current time', that particular data has to be retrieved...

Comment: Can't you create a view?

Comment: Every minute, every second, every millisecond ?

Comment: What if `call back time` already passed?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes... Is it possible?

Comment: That also to be retrieved...

Comment: I do not believe you have thought it through.  Retrieve where? What will happen to the set returned right before? Will it be overwritten?

Comment: Will you need to exclude those that already received a call back?

Comment: Get **all** your requirements together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm likely missing something here, but:

Something like `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE 'Call back time' >= NOW()`

I'd recommend not using simply equals, as has been said in the comments, because you might miss items.
If you update the callback time after you have retrieved the callback items, that should work as long as you do not do the query to get callbacks more than once every few seconds.

As was mentioned in the comments, this is just the start though. There are going to be other issues you'll have to deal with.

Comment: is there any to do this operation continuously in the background?

Comment: You can try using cron on any linux server, or scheduled tasks on windows.